# Gradle build variants Debug and Release are not showing. Google maps issue

Tags: android, google-maps, gradle

I am trying to get the basic Google Maps example to work

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start

Unfortunately, whenever I run it on the emulator using Geny, the screen is blank. After some searching, I am seeing others say that I should verify that both the app/src/debug/google_maps_api.xml and app/src/release/google_maps_api.xml have the key I created.

I have verified that app/src/main/res/values/google_maps_pi.xml has the key, but the other directories for debug and release do not exist.

I have synced my project with gradle files and still not seeing them.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding Google maps to an existing project, using this tutorial as a basis,

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start

then you must first create a new project using the maps activity wizard in Android Studio. Copy and paste the various differences mentioned in the tutorial such as the manifest.xml, build.gradle, and google_maps_api.xml.

The one thing I did not realize I needed to do was copy the directories app/src/debug and app/src/release from the new project to my existing one.

Once that is done then you can confirm that app/src/res/values/google_maps_pi.xml and app/src/res/release/google_maps_api.xml are using the same API you created.